# Convert ISO 8601 Date format string to PHP date format

Tags: php, datetime

I have a ISO date format string, `MMM d, y h:mm:ss a` for example. How do I convert it to the format acceptable by php `date` funtion? I want this as a result: `M j, y g:i:s A`.

Zend framework has a method to convert php format to iso:

```
public static function convertPhpToIsoFormat($format)
{
    if ($format === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $convert = array('d' => 'dd'  , 'D' => 'EE'  , 'j' => 'd'   , 'l' => 'EEEE', 'N' => 'eee' , 'S' => 'SS'  ,
                     'w' => 'e'   , 'z' => 'D'   , 'W' => 'ww'  , 'F' => 'MMMM', 'm' => 'MM'  , 'M' => 'MMM' ,
                     'n' => 'M'   , 't' => 'ddd' , 'L' => 'l'   , 'o' => 'YYYY', 'Y' => 'yyyy', 'y' => 'yy'  ,
                     'a' => 'a'   , 'A' => 'a'   , 'B' => 'B'   , 'g' => 'h'   , 'G' => 'H'   , 'h' => 'hh'  ,
                     'H' => 'HH'  , 'i' => 'mm'  , 's' => 'ss'  , 'e' => 'zzzz', 'I' => 'I'   , 'O' => 'Z'   ,
                     'P' => 'ZZZZ', 'T' => 'z'   , 'Z' => 'X'   , 'c' => 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZZZ',
                     'r' => 'r'   , 'U' => 'U');
    $values = str_split($format);
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($convert[$value]) === true) {
            $values[$key] = $convert[$value];
        }
    }

    return implode($values);
}
```

I want to convert the output of this method back to a php date format.

Comment: In order to parse a date, use `DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $string)` (hope I remember the name correctly, I'm spoiled by an IDE...). From that `DateTime`, you can extract the timestamp for use with `date()`, but you could as well use the builtin `format()` method.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I just want that format to be another format. e.g. `MMM d, y h:mm:ss a` to `M j, y g:i:s A`. I don't have any actual date to parse or format.

Comment: sorry, withdrawing my answer - it's early here and the coffee hasn't kicked in yet!

Answer (score 1):

try this instead, uses `preg_match()` to split your string into tokens and delimiters, converts your token if it exists in the `$convert` array then glues it back together with your delimiter into `$result`

```
public static function convertIsoToPhpFormat($format) {
    if ($format === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $convert = array('dd' => 'd'  , 'EE' => 'D' , 'd' => 'j'   , 'EEEE' => 'l', 'eee' => 'N' , 'SS' => 'S'  ,
                     'e' => 'w'   , 'D' => 'z'   , 'ww' => 'W'  , 'MMMM' => 'F', 'MM' => 'm'  , 'MMM' => 'M' ,
                     'M' => 'n'   , 'ddd' => 't' , 'l' => 'L'   , 'YYYY' => 'o' , 'yyyy' => 'Y' , 'yy' => 'y'  ,
                     'a' => 'a'   , 'A' => 'A'   , 'B' => 'B'   , 'h' => 'g'   , 'H' => 'G'   , 'hh' => 'h'  ,
                     'HH' => 'H'  , 'mm' => 'i'  , 'ss' => 's'  , 'zzzz' => 'e', 'I' => 'I'   , 'Z' => 'O'  ,
                     'ZZZZ' => 'P', 'z' => 'T'   , 'X' => 'Z'   , 'ssZZZZ' => 'se' ,
                     'r' => 'r'   , 'U' => 'U');

    // todo: add exceptions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZZZ
    $result = '';
    while (preg_match('/^([^- :,]+)([- :,]*)(.*)$/',$format,$arr_preg)) {
      if (isset($convert[$arr_preg[1]]) === true) {
        $result .= $convert[$arr_preg[1]];
      } else {
        $result .= $arr_preg[1];
      }
      $result .= $arr_preg[2];
      $format = $arr_preg[3];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It solves the case I mentioned, but it fails on `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZZZ` for example. It should be converted to `c`. Or `HH:mm:ssZZZZ` should be converted to `H:i:se`.

Comment: @Padram, there will be exceptions (my knowledge of ISO 8601 is limited). Make this a start, take it and run with it - use your creativity (I see you have javascript/php/c# experience) make it into what you need. When you are happy with your creation post it back here so we can all share. Good luck :)